# Shell script print result by column

Tags: bash, shell

I am pretty confused.

I have a value output like:

```
jstat -gc 7110

S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
52416.0 52416.0 178.1   0.0   419456.0 261407.3  524288.0   30663.4   50272.0 30745.7    898   10.393   6      0.243   10.636
```

I have already retrieved each of the key and value but just want to display the results like:

```
SOC : 52416.0
S1C : 52416.0
```

Help!! My code:

```
jstat -gc 7110 | tr -s '' | cut -d '' -f 1,14 | while read line
do
#echo $line
lineinfo=(`echo $line  | tr -s '' | cut -d '' -f 1,15`)
for (( i=0; i<${#lineinfo[@]}; i++ ))
do
echo "$i" : ${lineinfo[i]}
printf "%s\n"
done
done
```

Comment: IMHO this is not a bash task. Use python, ruby or any other language that has a dictionary- / map-like data structure. Under 10 lines of code, readable, maintainable and - unlike any bash solution - even testable. Just saying :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
52416.0 52416.0 178.1   0.0   419456.0 261407.3  524288.0   30663.4   50272.0 30745.7    898   10.393   6      0.243   10.636

$ sed -E 's/\s+/\n/g' ip.txt | pr -2ts' : '
S0C : 52416.0
S1C : 52416.0
S0U : 178.1
S1U : 0.0
EC : 419456.0
EU : 261407.3
OC : 524288.0
OU : 30663.4
PC : 50272.0
PU : 30745.7
YGC : 898
YGCT : 10.393
FGC : 6
FGCT : 0.243
GCT : 10.636
```

Using `sed` to replace white-spaces with newline, then using `pr` to style the output

Answer (score 1):

If the columns match up perfectly, you could do something like this with awk:

```
awk -v OFS=' : ' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if (NR == 1) key[i] = $i; else val[i] = $i } 
 END { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print key[i], val[i] }' file
```

Loop through the fields on each line, assigning keys and values to separate arrays. After reading both lines, print the combined output.

`print` inserts the Output Field Separator `OFS` between each field, so set it to `' : '` to get your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v OFS=: 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i;next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  print   a[i],$i}' infile
S0C:52416.0
S1C:52416.0
S0U:178.1
S1U:0.0
EC:419456.0
EU:261407.3
OC:524288.0
OU:30663.4
PC:50272.0
PU:30745.7
YGC:898
YGCT:10.393
FGC:6
FGCT:0.243
GCT:10.636
```

Comment: If you've gone to the trouble of setting `OFS`, then why use `printf`?

Comment: ...and if you're gonna use `print`, then why not use a comma?

Comment: @TomFenech ,true I updated my answer. Initially I thought of `printf` formatting but later thought of leaving it for OP.   +1 to yours too.

Answer (score 0):

`tr` twice and `pr` for output control:

```
$ tr -s \  '\n' file | pr -2 -t -s" : "
S0C : 52416.0
S1C : 52416.0
S0U : 178.1
S1U : 0.0
EC : 419456.0
EU : 261407.3
OC : 524288.0
OU : 30663.4
PC : 50272.0
PU : 30745.7
YGC : 898
YGCT : 10.393
FGC : 6
FGCT : 0.243
GCT : 10.636
```

Or `awk` and `pr`:

```
$ awk '$1=$1' OFS="\n" file |pr -2 -t -s" : "
```

ie. `$1=$1` rebuilds the record and `OFS="\n"` changes the output field separator to newline. `pr` makes sweet columns.

Comment: `tr -s ' ' '\n' < file | pr -2ts' : '` produces the same output for me - what do the two `tr`s do?